# URL rewrite in .net 4.0 with querystring

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

how can i get Routes URL from

www.xyz.com/department.aspx?p=9&c=8

to

www.xyz.com/department?p=9&c=8

i have try with lots of example but not able to get it done.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("department", "/department{*queryvalues}", "~/department.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "p", @"\d{4}" } });
```

Comment: please clarify did you done it?

Comment: no @harry180 ,help me if you have any idea on it thanks

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc? Can't imagine why you would have .aspx if you were

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that this is the answer you wanted.
I've found that using routing in Web forms a problematic affair.
Its easier to use a Url Rewriter module which intercepts requests and rewrites the url so it gets sent to the correct page.

This is an article from scott gu on how to do it.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

If you have any questions on this please ask in the comments or start a chat?